# how to change icons and screens in phonegap?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

All I can find is documents and the like that are like:

`Put this in your config file`, `make sure the icon.png is in your root folder`.. ok. I have tried this all I don't even know how many $*U%)#ing times and how many different ways.. either no changed get applied, and the default phonegap logos show up.. or the app crashes:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'config.xml parse error
>   line 4 col 40'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x19a012 0x2b6be7e 0x199e78 0x17e1665 0x1b552 0x1829a08 0x5a1c2af 0x5a36745 0x5a3e25a 0x5a404e5 0x5a3ff07
>   0x18298fe 0x1829890 0x1829b46 0x1829bfa 0xbd22 0xab30 0xabee 0x20392
>   0x4b4e1e 0xacae 0x2047b 0x1fc3c 0x3d3157 0x3d3747 0x3d494b 0x3e5cb5
>   0x3e6beb 0x3d8698 0x392edf9 0x392ead0 0x10fbf5 0x10f962 0x140bb6
>   0x13ff44 0x13fe1b 0x3d417a 0x3d5ffc 0x1f86c 0x1f7cd) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminate called throwing an exception

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="img/icons/ios/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="img/icons/ios/icon72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="img/icons/ios/icon114.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<!-- retina iPad support: PhoneGap 2.5.0+ only -->
<icon src="img/icons/ios/icon144.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
```

Anyone got any idea's what I might be doing wrong? cause I believe I am following the docs pretty well, and this apparently seems to be a common problem for people. But other than people saying put the above in your config and magic will happen, no one ever resolves the issues, or confirms it?

Comment: 3.0 I believe.. I just recently started this project

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same issue but only finding either unresolved answers, or the "put it in your config" cookie-cut answer